# Undefined variable in PHP json_encode

Tags: php, pdo

I am getting a PHP error undefined variable in my code. I am using PDO to json_encode the output. When I test my code I am getting that error. How can I fix and avoid this in the future? Is my code structure ok? or do I need to improve it in order to avoid this problem

> Undefined variable: ar

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT UserID, UsrPassword, ContactID, UserTypeID, UserStatus, ClientUpdate, ServerUpdate, Deleted FROM tblUsers WHERE ContactID = :contactid AND ServerUpdate > :lastchecked AND Deleted != :deleted", $cursor);
$sql->bindValue(":contactid", $ContactID);
$sql->bindValue(":lastchecked", $LastChecked);
$sql->bindValue(":deleted", 1);

if($sql->execute()){
    $count = $sql->rowCount();

    if($count > 0){
        while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
            $decr = CryptRC4(FromHexDump($row['UsrPassword']), $key);

            if($row['ServerUpdate'] > $row['ClientUpdate']){
                $lupdate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($row['ServerUpdate']));
            }
            else{
                $lupdate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($row['ClientUpdate']));
            }

            $ar[] = array(
                'UserID' => $row['UserID'],
                'UsrPassword' => $decr,
                'ContactID' => $row['ContactID'],
                'UserTypeID' => $row['UserTypeID'],
                'UserStatus' => $row['UserStatus'],
                'Deleted' => $row['Deleted'],
                'LastUpdated' => $lupdate
            );
        }
    }
}
else{
    $ar[] = array(
        "Message" => $sql->errorInfo(),
        "sql" => $sql
    );
}

print json_encode($ar);
```

Comment: Just add `$ar = [];` before the first if-statement. The problem is when `if($count > 0)`  evaluates as false (the query doesn't return anything), then `$ar`  doesn't get defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems `if($count > 0){` condition is not satisfied ,Declare ar before this,hope this helps

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT UserID, UsrPassword, ContactID, UserTypeID, UserStatus, ClientUpdate, ServerUpdate, Deleted FROM tblUsers WHERE ContactID = :contactid AND ServerUpdate > :lastchecked AND Deleted != :deleted", $cursor);
    $sql->bindValue(":contactid", $ContactID);
    $sql->bindValue(":lastchecked", $LastChecked);
    $sql->bindValue(":deleted", 1);
    $ar = array();

    if($sql->execute()){
        $count = $sql->rowCount();

        if($count > 0){
            while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
                $decr = CryptRC4(FromHexDump($row['UsrPassword']), $key);

                if($row['ServerUpdate'] > $row['ClientUpdate']){
                    $lupdate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($row['ServerUpdate']));
                }
                else{
                    $lupdate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($row['ClientUpdate']));
                }

                $ar[] = array(
                    'UserID' => $row['UserID'],
                    'UsrPassword' => $decr,
                    'ContactID' => $row['ContactID'],
                    'UserTypeID' => $row['UserTypeID'],
                    'UserStatus' => $row['UserStatus'],
                    'Deleted' => $row['Deleted'],
                    'LastUpdated' => $lupdate
                );
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $ar[] = array(
            "Message" => $sql->errorInfo(),
            "sql" => $sql
        );
    }

    print_r(json_encode($ar));
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare $ar variable as a array before if statement so the scope of variable is not limited and you can access this outside If else.

```
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT UserID, UsrPassword, ContactID, UserTypeID, UserStatus, ClientUpdate, ServerUpdate, Deleted FROM tblUsers WHERE ContactID = :contactid AND ServerUpdate > :lastchecked AND Deleted != :deleted", $cursor);
    $sql->bindValue(":contactid", $ContactID);
    $sql->bindValue(":lastchecked", $LastChecked);
    $sql->bindValue(":deleted", 1);
    $ar = array();

    if(){
     // You code goes here
    }
    else{
     // You code goes here
    }

    print_r($ar);
```